# How would you correctly return a collection of objects asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, system.reactive, entity-framework-core

I need to define methods in my core interface that return lists. My project heavily relies on the use of async/await so I need to define my core references/interfaces as asynchronous as possible. I also use EF7 for my data-access layer. I currently use `IAsyncEnumerable` everywhere.

I am currently deciding whether to keep using `IAsyncEnumerable` or to revert back to using `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`. `IAsyncEnumerable` seems promising at this point. EF7 is [using](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/77) it as well. The trouble is, I don't know and can't figure out how to use it. There is almost nothing on the [website](http://rx.codeplex.com/documentation) that tells anyone how to use **Ix.Net**. There's a `ToAsyncEnumerable` extension that I can use on `IEnumerable` objects but this wouldn't do anything asynchronously (or does it??). Another drawback is that given the below signature:

```
IAsyncEnumerable GetPersons();
```

Because this isn't a function that returns Task, I can't use async/await inside the function block.

On the other hand, my gut is telling me that I should stick with using `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`. This of course has it's problems as well. EF does not have an extension method that returns this type. It has a `ToArrayAsync` and `ToListAsync` extension method but this of course requires you to call await inside the method because `Task<T>` isn't covariant. This potentially is a problem because this creates an extra *operation* which could be avoided if I simply return the `Task` object.

My questions is: Should I keep using `IAsyncEnumerable` (preferred) or should I change everything back to `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` (not preferred)? I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: You seem to understand the drawbacks of each option. All that's left are opinions. Mine is on the side of IAsyncEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you back that up with why you think it's the better option?

Comment: because it's lazy and asynchronous. And it's the future.

Comment: I agree with it being lazy and that is what I like about it. Do you have anything that could help me learn how to use it though?

Comment: Trial and error? This is all new stuff. You can clone their code and look around in it to see which operations are available...

Comment: What about `IObservable<T>`? Have you considered that? It's precisely used for asynchronously returning collections.

Comment: The main reason would be because my DAL is using EF and EF does not have a built-in thing that returns `IObservable<T>`. Even if I could make it happen, it would be like adding an abstraction on top of an existing abstraction and just overcomplicates it a bit too much. It is a good option if I had to build my own DAL from objects in the `System.Data` though.

Comment: @opiants - Don't forget to do the `@username` when replying. EF doesn't have anything that returns `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` either. You can just build whatever signature suits. I'll bet that `IObservable<T>` leads to much cleaner code.

Comment: @Enigmativity - You are right that it doesn't but as said in my post, you can `await .ToListAsync()` or `await .ToArrayAsync() ` and it will work but won't be lazy and spins another thread operation. I could probably use `.ToObservable` but because EF don't support that under the hood, it won't be async and will defeat the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve. Also, using `IObservable<T>` won't fix the problem of me not being able to use `await` inside the method (same drawback with using `IAsyncEnumerable` as stated)

Comment: @opiants - Just for the record, Observables are async and you can use `await` inside them.

Comment: @Enigmativity You lost me there. How can you use the `await` keyword in: `public IObservable<Foo> GetFoo(){ /* some code*/}`

Comment: @opiants - It's more like this: `public async Task<int> Foo() { return await Observable.Range(0, 10); }`

Answer (score 6):

I would go with `IAsyncEnumerable`. It allows you to keep your operations both asynchronous and lazy.

Without it you need to return `Task<IEnumerble>` which means you're loading all the results into memory. This in many cases meaning querying and holding more memory than needed.

The classic case is having a query that the user calls `Any` on. If it's `Task<IEnumerable>` it will load all the results into memory first, and if it's `IAsyncEnumerable` loading one result will be enough.

Also relevant is that with `Task<IEnumerable>` you need to hold the entire result set in memory at the same time while with `IAsyncEnumerable` you can "stream" the results a few at a time.

Also, that's the direction the ecosystem is heading. It was added by reactive extension, by a [new library suggested by Stephen Toub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/pull/335) just this week and will probably be [supported in the next version of C# natively](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/261).

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` has been a [champion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/43) for quite a while now. Hopefully, it'll make it in C# 8.

Answer (score 2):

You should just use `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` return types. The reason is simply that you don’t want to lazily run a new query against the database for *every* object you want to read, so just let EF query those at once, and then pass that collection on.

Of course you could make the async list into an async enumerable then, but why bother. Once you have the data in memory, there’s no reason to artificially delay access to it.

Comment: Thanks. What do you recommend the best way is to return a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` using EF without using `await`?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use await? Just do `await return someEfLinqQuery.ToListAsync()`

Comment: Because it creates a unnecessary async operation especially when you don't need to await on anything inside the function except for the .ToListAsync of course.

Comment: The async operation is already running, but yes, it creates another async context. But doing `return await Something()`  is better than just returning the original task as this will make sure that exceptions are encapsulated in the task (and don’t throw immediately).